# fileupload is not saving a file in online server

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

fileupload control is not saving a file in on-line server while it is working fine in local host. The same code is working in other side. Hosting site is Bigrock

```
string extF = Path.GetExtension(pFileUpload.FileName.ToString());
string photo = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + extF;
if (pFileUpload.HasFile)
{
    pFileUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/pro/") + photo);
}
```

> Access to the path 'D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\techmutnauq.com\Sportsday\Images\pro\0070b1fb-8be4-447f-b33e-71b11b0a1400.jpg'
>   is denied.

Comment: Does the account your site runs as have write permissions in the destination directory?

Comment: yes there is no such issue

Comment: Surround your code with try/catch and if there is an exception spit the message as output, in that way you will know what's happening, else it's like looking to a black box.

Comment: does the directory exist?

Comment: Access to the path 'D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\techmutnauq.com\Sportsday\Images\pro\0070b1fb-8be4-447f-b33e-71b11b0a1400.jpg' is denied.